# Center of mass doubt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

In physics, the center of mass of a distribution of mass in space (sometimes referred to as the balance point) is the unique point where the weighted relative position of the distributed mass sums to zero. This is what I read in Wikipedia about the center of mass. How does the weighted relative position of masses with respect to the point affect the fact that it only causes linear acceleration but not angular acceleration?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/726001/330899

Comment: COM has nothing to do with type of movement. It depends on exact application of force. For example, gravity can make a linear acceleration- ball falls down to the ground. But it can equally produce a torque about some pivot point- imagine drunk person falls down from a standing position to a laying one. In that case gravity produced angular acceleration about a pivot point residing in drunk person foots.